# Is there a way to contact the owner of a Analytics account when only the UA account number is known?

Tags: google-analytics

I have taken over a website for a company and their former webmaster does not know who have access to the analytics account used on their "old" website.

I obviously got their UA account number, but nobody knows who has access to that.

Is there a way for to contact the owner through that account number?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you just create a new Google Analytics and/or Google Webmaster Tools account and validate the ownership by changing the code. Otherwise, there is no way to reverse the ownership of an account. Google does not give tools for this. But they are used to websites changing management/ownership.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to contact the owner for access to past details, then you should instead be able to reclaim the account via Google analytics.

Account Recovery Process https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/oFoGKQooXGA/LbgQYtKM1h4J

With Screenshots http://savvydealer.com/reclaim-your-google-analytics-account/